# Access query parameter from control

Tags: ms-access, vba

Fish out of water looking for direction/advice not necessarily code (Although that would be helpful). I am an ME that designs machines for a living and I am trying to automate an existing 2010 Access database used for engineering part numbers. I want the user to select the project number and have the next available part number automatically appear in the part number field.

I have tried unsuccessfully using ADO and DAO examples from the various sources to pass a parameter that is based on the value of a form control to a select query. My latest attempt is as follows:

```
Private Sub ctlProject_AfterUpdate()

Dim dblProject As Double

dblProject = Me.ctlProject.Value

MsgBox "The curret project number is " & dblProject, vbOKOnly, "Project Number"


Const cstrQueryName As String = "qryDetails"
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQueryName)
qdf.Parameters("Project") = dblProject

' Open recordset on the query
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

rst.MoveLast

Debug.Print ("Project ID: " & rst!Project)

rst.Close
qdf.Close
dbs.Close

End Sub
```

Code produces a "Run-Time Error '3265'. Item not found in this collection" that stems from this line of code:

```
qdf.Parameters("Project") = dblProject
```

Original Source code [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/queries/#AssigningParameters)

I have had similar failures using the ADO Command object. I would greatly appreciate any help or recommendations for references/resources. I have been using "Access 2003 vba programmers's manual" by WROX and "Access 2010: the missing manual" as hardcopy references.

Here is the code from the SQL view of qryDetails:

```
SELECT tblDetails.Project, tblDetails.Number, tblDetails.Title, tblDetails.Initials,
tblDetails.IssuedOn
FROM tblDetails
WHERE (((tblDetails.Project)=[Project]));
```

Comment: Silly question really but judging by your error are you sure the query `qryDetails` expects a Parameter called "Project"?

Comment: Please show us the SQL from `qryDetails`.

Comment: @Lankymart Short answer is I think so.  In response to @HansUp request I added the SQL view from the `qryDetails`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm skeptical about *Project* as the parameter name because there is a field with the same name.  It's also a reserved word, but I'm unsure whether that is an extra challenge here.

Revise *qryDetails* to use a different name for the parameter.

```sql
SELECT tblDetails.Project, tblDetails.Number, tblDetails.Title, tblDetails.Initials,
tblDetails.IssuedOn
FROM tblDetails
WHERE (((tblDetails.Project)=[pProject]));
```

And don't forget to revise the VBA to use that new name ...

```vb
qdf.Parameters("pProject") = dblProject
```

If you still have trouble after those changes, see what Access thinks about your query parameter(s).

```vb
Const cstrQueryName As String = "qryDetails"
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQueryName)
MsgBox "Parameters.Count: " & qdf.Parameters.Count
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    MsgBox "Parameter Name: " & prm.Name
Next
```